# Please help. I want to ensure 1 case per lead

Tags: apex, trigger

Ensure only 1 Case with this Type is open
at the same time for every Lead record

```
trigger createCase on Lead (after insert) {

List <Case> caseToCreate = new List <Case>(); 
Set<Id> oneCasecreated = new Map<Id, Lead>
    ([Select Id From Lead where Id in (Select Lead From Case where Lead != null)]).keySet();

    for(Lead l : Trigger.new){
        if(l.RecordTypeId == '0123t0000005nAYAAY'){
            
            Case c = new Case();
            c.Type = 'Application';
            c.OwnerId='3D00G3t000002cjR5';
            caseToCreate.add(c);

        }
        if(l.RecordTypeId == '0123t0000005nATAAY'){
            
            Case c = new Case();
            c.Type = 'Application';
            c.OwnerId='3D00G3t000002cjRK';
            caseToCreate.add(c);
            
        }
        
    }

try{
    insert caseToCreate;

}
catch (system.Dmlexception e) {
    system.debug (e);
}

}
```

Error here:

```
Set<Id> oneCasecreated = new Map<Id, Lead>
       ([Select Id From Lead where Id in (Select Lead From Case where Lead != null)]).keySet();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here.

```
([Select Id From Lead where Id in (Select Lead From Case where Lead != null)]).keySet();
```

[There is no field called `Lead` on `Case`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_case.htm); the standard reference shows no relationship at all between Lead and Case. If you working with an optional feature, managed package, or custom development that establishes such a relationship, you must query based on the API name of the schema involved.

```
    if(l.RecordTypeId == '0123t0000005nAYAAY'){
```

You should never hard-code Salesforce Ids of any kind. You should always use Describe API methods or SOQL queries to obtain the Salesforce Ids you need.

Here, you should be using [Describe methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_RecordTypeInfo.htm), such as

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult d = Schema.SObjectType.Lead;
Id recordTypeId = d.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('YOUR_RECORD_TYPE').getRecordTypeId();
```

or similar.

```
3D00G3t000002cjRK
```

What is the key prefix `3D0`? This is neither a User nor a Group.

```
try{
    insert caseToCreate;

}
catch (system.Dmlexception e) {
    system.debug (e);
}
```

You should never catch and swallow an exception like this. If this exception is considered not to threaten the integrity of your data, you should be using a logging and notification framework to bring it to the attention of your system administrator for action. Putting an exception in a debug log does nothing but hide problem behavior and risk your users' trust (and their data).

As an aside,

> Ensure only 1 Case with this Type is open at the same time for every Lead record

your trigger does nothing of the kind. This seems to be fulfilling an entirely different requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.

Comment: Just started learning and just want to assign queue in a case.

Comment: Whatever that Id is, you do need to query for any object that you want to use. Never hard-code ids; you'll end up having to make a deployment when your org data changes.

Comment: Yes already did. Btw, this trigger was meant to create a case record. If I want to ensure only 1 Case with this Type is open at the same time for every Lead record. Should I create another trigger or can I insert that code here? I'm totally new here.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you explore _trigger frameworks_, which will help you structure your trigger code effectively as it grows beyond doing just one thing. You'll find many with a search; Kevin O'Hara's is popular and approachable.